# React: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type but only when I pass it to a child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a basic increment app in react with the following code. Passing in the `handleClick` function into the first button works fine, however passing it to a child component `IcrementButton` that returns the exact same button gives the error:
`` React: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object ``. Why is it working for the first button but not the child component button and how can it be fixed? thanks in advance.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const IncrementButton = (handleClick) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>+</button>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  const [num, setNum] = useState(0)
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('clicked')
    setNum(prev => prev += 1)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{num}</div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>+</button>
      <IncrementButton handleClick={handleClick} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Typo, you neglected to destructure the `handleClick` callback from the props object. Voted to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the IncrementButton is a custom component all props passed to it is sent as an object and to access it you need to use `props.property`. There are 2 ways to get your code to work.

1. Use props.property

```
const IncrementButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.handleClick}>+</button>
  )
}
```

2. Destructure the props object

```
const IncrementButton = ({handleClick}) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>+</button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't destructure handle click. Try the code below

```
const IncrementButton = ({handleClick}) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>+</button>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That does not work because `React` passes every props on a `Component` as a single `Object`.

You have two ways to get `handleClick` function reference.

1. Destructure props (`es6`)

```
const IncrementButton = ({handleClick}) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>+</button>
  )
}
```

2. Use `props.propertyName`

```
const IncrementButton = (props) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.handleClick}>+</button>
  )
}
```